# Javascript loaded but not triggered in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I was trying to load a `parallax` `jQuery` file but eventhough it's loaded in the index file, it doesn't trigger anything... Not even a simple `alert('test')`

**functions.php**

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-jquery', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-parallax', get_template_directory_uri() . "/scripts/parallax.js");
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-mainjs', get_template_directory_uri() . "/scripts/main.js" );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

**Example main.js**

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    alert('test')
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Lookin at console, there are no errors. Everything is loaded just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_style` is used for CSS files, for scripts, it should be `wp_enqueue_script`.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid mistake! However, when I change it to `wp_enqueue_script` it breaks with error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: And which directory it tried to access? Now probably is just an issue with paths.

Comment: It fails on all three, so also the jQuery link which is just an URL